# Custom Windows Decorate Java

Tags: java

I want to know, if is there anyway to customize the windows decorate in java.. like a theme in windows.... because I can't find any solution in google.
I want to do something similar like "Steam" you can see the picture below.

[Steam Windows Decorate](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpo0fz2oh0a0td9/Captura.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library features [Synth Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html), but by default it does not support window decorations (you must emulate the title bar & buttons).

There are various 3rd party libraries loosely based on either Synth or Nimbus (the latter provides all L&F default values, which might be convenient (or not)). You can pick one based on your context (you haven't specified any), because some may be subject to licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:
[Shaped and Translucent Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

They added it as a late Java 6 feature, so Java 7 you can count on it being fully supported.